# The response from API is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I'm attempting to make an authentication system using tokens. This works via sending a get request with a token in it and the API is supposed to give information back. I'm encountering an error which is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Error' of undefined` and the error is pointing to this line `if (UserData.Error == "Token not valid") {return false}`. So I'm guessing this means the response of API is not getting put into `UserData`. The API works fine and here is the response if the token is right:

```
{
    "username": "admin",
    "is_staff": true,
    "email": "admin@gmail.com"
}
```

Here is the response when token is not right

```
{
    "Error": "Token not valid"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
function isAuthenticated() {
    const authtoken = localStorage.getItem('AuthToken')
    if (authtoken == null) {
        return false
    } else {
        let UserData;
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/token/?token=${authtoken}`).then(function(request) {
            UserData = request.data
        })
        if (UserData.Error == "Token not valid") {return false}
        else {return UserData}
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I do not think it does

Comment: It does, that `if (UserData.Error == "Token not valid") {return false}` doesn't wait  for  the axios call directly above it.  It executes immediately which means that `UserData` will ***never*** be defined by the time you reach that if.

Comment: Have you implemented the error handling like `catch` on the fetch or the `axios.get`? I think you should put the `catch` after `then`

Comment: I have tried those solutions, They did not work and I could not understand most of the code (I'm fairly new to React and JS)

Comment: I tried using catch, The result is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ajax request will work in asynchronous manner in js, we can make the call as synchrous with `async await`.

```js
async function isAuthenticated() {
    const authtoken = localStorage.getItem('AuthToken')
    if (authtoken == null) {
        return false
    } else {
        let UserData;
        UserData = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/token/?token=${authtoken}`).then(function(request) {
          return request.data
        })
        if (UserData.Error == "Token not valid") {return false}
        else {return UserData}
    }
}

# while executing use await
userData = await isAuthenticated()
```